# Deserialize to type with missing or extra properties

Tags: c#, msgpack

I'm using messagepack (https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) to send information back and forth. I create my own types that I send and deserialize on the receiving end. The problem that I have is, that I sometimes need to add or remove properties because of new features. This means that when I deserialize, at the receiving end, I'm getting a missing property or unknown property error because the receiving does not know about these changes (production).
What is the strategy to be able to send updated types and still be able to deserialize them accepting missing or added properties without failing the deserialization.
I've searched everywhere and looked in the documentation, but cannot find the answer.

Comment: You generally need to use a data format which allows you to add/remove elements without breaking binary compatibility. One common way is to use a tagged data format, such as Protobuf

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the example DTO class you have defined to serialize/deserialize the data. Also include the source code on how exactly you are serialize/deserialize your classes, specially the message pack options. You should at least look for the `keyAsPropertyName` setting, even though it results in bigger serialized data.

Comment: Thank you @canton7 and that is not possible with messagepack c#? I need to change serializer?